# How to write a MySQL SELECT Query to achieve this result?

Tags: mysql, select

I have an abstract problem which can be simplified as the following problem: Assume that we have two tables `persons` and `names` that look as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM persons;
+----+-------+--------+
| id | name  | fan_of |
+----+-------+--------+
|  1 | alice |      2 |
|  2 | bob   |      4 |
|  3 | carol |      1 |
|  4 | dave  |      3 |
|  5 | bob   |      2 |
+----+-------+--------+
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM names;
+----+-------+--------+
| id | name  | active |
+----+-------+--------+
|  1 | alice |      1 |
|  2 | bob   |      1 |
|  3 | carol |      0 |
|  4 | dave  |      1 |
+----+-------+--------+
```

Every person (a row in the `persons`) table is a fan of itself or another person (represented by that other persons `id` in the `fan_of` column). The `names` table contains names that can be active or inactive.

For a given offset `k`, I want to `SELECT` the persons (rows of `persons`) that have the `k+1`-th active name as their name or that have one of these people as their fans. For example, if the offset is 1, the second active name is bob and hence I want to select all people with the name bob plus the people that have one of these bobs as their fans, which is in this example the row of persons with `id`=4. This means that I want to have the result:

```
+----+------+--------+
| id | name | fan_of |
+----+------+--------+
|  2 | bob  |      4 |
|  4 | dave |      3 |
|  5 | bob  |      2 |
+----+------+--------+
```

What I have so far is the following query:

```
  1 SELECT * FROM persons WHERE
  2     EXISTS (
  3         SELECT * FROM (
  4             SELECT * FROM names WHERE active=true LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
  5         ) AS selectedname WHERE (selectedname.name=persons.name)
  6     )
  7     OR
  8     EXISTS (
  9         SELECT * FROM(
 10             SELECT * FROM persons WHERE EXISTS (
 11                 SELECT * FROM (
 12                     SELECT * FROM names WHERE active=true LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
 13                 ) AS selectedname WHERE (selectedname.name=persons.name)
 14             )
 15         ) AS personswiththatname  WHERE persons.id=personswiththatname.fan_of
 16     );
```

It gives me the desired result from above but please note that it is inefficient because the lines 3-5 and 11-13 are the same.

I have the following two questions:

1. What can be done to avoid this inefficiency?
2. I actually need to distinguish between those rows that came from the
   `name` condition (here the rows with name=bob) and those that came
   from the `fan_of` condition (here the row with name=dave). This
   could be done in the application code but then I would need another
   database query before to find out the `k+1`-th active name and this might
   be slow (please correct me if this is the better solution). I would
   rather prefer an additional column `z` that helps me to distinguish
   like

   ```
   +----+------+--------+---+
   | id | name | fan_of | z |
   +----+------+--------+---+
   |  2 | bob  |      4 | 1 |
   |  4 | dave |      3 | 0 |
   |  5 | bob  |      2 | 1 |
   +----+------+--------+---+
   ```

   How can such an output be achieved?

Comment: Based on your example, should:
"For a given offset k, I want to SELECT the persons (rows of persons) that have the k+1-th active name as their name or that have one of these people as their fans"

Not actually mean "I want to select the each person from `person` who has either the k+1-th active name, or each person who is a fan of another with that name?

That's the only way your description makes sense to me

Comment: @ChrisJ No, I mean it as it is stated, but I admit that it does not make sense as a real-world example. What I want is all people with that name plus all that are referred by the `fan_of` column.

Comment: So 'Dave' is retrieved because Bob is a fan of him, and Bob is the nth (selected) active name?

Comment: @ChrisJ Exactly, I will make this more explicit. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I can get the minimum you want to achieve using parameters (should this be an option).

It's not pretty, but I can't see a simple way of achieving what you're asking for, so this is what I have so far....(set @offset to suit 'k')

```
SET @offset = 1;
SET @name = (SELECT name FROM (select name, @rank := @rank +1 as Rank from names n, (SELECT @rank := 0) r where active !=0) as activeRanked where activeRanked.rank = (1 + @offset));
select
a.*
From persons a
where (a.name = @name) OR (a.id IN (SELECT fan_of from persons where name = @name));
```

If you still don't have an answer by the time I've had food, I'll look at part 2.

(hopefully I've read your brief correctly)

P.S.  I've kept the @name SQL in a single line as it seems to read better in this context.

Edit:  Here's a pretty messy but functional indicator of source, using your example.  Z = 1 is where the row is from the `name`, '0' is from `fan_of`

```
SET @offset = 1;
SET @name = (SELECT name FROM (select name, @rank := @rank +1 as Rank from names n, (SELECT @rank := 0) r where active !=0) as activeRanked where activeRanked.rank = (1 + @offset));
select
a.*,'1' as z
From persons a
where (a.name = @name)
union
select
a.*,'0' as z
From persons a
where (a.id IN (SELECT fan_of from persons where name = @name));
```

Distinct ID Query:

```
SET @offset = 1;
SET @name = (SELECT name FROM (select name, @rank := @rank +1 as Rank from names n, (SELECT @rank := 0) r where active !=0) as activeRanked where activeRanked.rank = (1 + @offset));
SELECT id, name, fan_of, z FROM
(select
distinct a.id,
a.name,
a.fan_of,
1 as z
From persons a
where (a.name = @name)
union
select
distinct a.id,
a.name,
a.fan_of,
0 as z
From persons a
where (a.id IN (SELECT fan_of from persons where name = @name))
ORDER BY z desc) qry
GROUP BY id;
```

This produces:

```
+----+------+--------+---+
| id | name | fan_of | z | 
+----+------+--------+---+
| 2  | bob  |    4   | 1 | 
| 5  | bob  |    2   | 1 | 
| 4  | dave |    3   | 0 |
+----+------+--------+---+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try it out tomorrow and tick this answer as useful for now, in my timezone, its late and I am only a MySQL beginner (who didn't use parameters before)...

Comment: No problem -  I've added an option for achieving part 2.  Not the most elaborate, but it's functional.

Comment: It works!! But is there any way to avoid the double selection of the row with `id`=2 and `name`=bob? It is listed twice one time with `z`=1 and another time with `z`=0. I only want the row with `z`=1.

Comment: I'm on my phone at the moment, so can't verify, but if you make the select explicit and distinct ID, it may resolve this.   I'll edit the reply.

Comment: Duplicates still appear in Server version: 10.1.26-MariaDB-0+deb9u1 Debian 9.1. Maybe a GROUP BY id can help? But from the duplicates, I need to keep those with `z`=1 and I don't know which of the duplicates GROUPBY will keep.

Comment: I've edited the last query.   It will group by ID, but sorted `by z desc`, meaning the `z=1` will take precedent in the grouping

Comment: To get ths nice ordering, I have to move the `ORDER BY z desc` to the very end. Thank you very much!!